# How to use "const unordered_map"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constants, unordered-map

I'd like to declare a `const unordered_map` but I get compiler error, and I can't figure out the correct syntax. All examples I've found but one are non const, and I'm doing it exactly as the only const example I know, but I get compiler errors. Here is my code:

```
typedef const std::unordered_map<std::string,int> StringIntMap;
StringIntMap string_to_case {
   {"get",1},
   {"add",2}
};
```

vs 110 gives me:

```
Error   1   error C2601: 'string_to_case' : local function definitions are illegal
```

or if I put an equal sign between `string_to_case` and the bracket I get:

```
Error   1   error C2552: 'string_to_case' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
```

vs 120_CTP_Nov2012 instead gives me the following with or without equal sign:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::unordered_map<std::string,int,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Getting the same error, visual studio 2019. Works immediately after removing `const`

Answer (score 1):

This works with gcc 6.1.1:

```
$ cat t.C
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

typedef const std::unordered_map<std::string,int> StringIntMap;
StringIntMap string_to_case = {
   {"get",1},
   {"add",2}
};
$ g++ -g -c -std=c++1z -o t.o t.C
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160621 (Red Hat 6.1.1-3)
```

You're not doing anything wrong. You either hit a compiler bug, your compiler does not support the latest C++ standard.

Comment: thank you, but visual studio (at least the versions I have access to, vs2012 update 5 and vs2012 CTP nov 2012), neither accepts it :(

Comment: Agreed. You need VS 15 or better (compiler version 19).

Comment: It takes me about one hour to install the latest version of Fedora Linux on a spare box, with gcc 6.1.1 "out of the box". If you want to use a modern C++ compiler, supporting the latest C++ standards, you should be able to solve this problem fairly quickly.

Comment: thank you Sam, my compiler feels way out of date at this point. I find myself choosing inferior libs choices and trying to find workarounds bc of it :(

Comment: @AbsolutelyFreeWeb So download Visual Studio 2015 Community edition? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx